# Scrubbing audio player similar to SoundCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-streaming, soundcloud, audio-recording

I need to create a custom audio player interface on iOS similar to the one used by SoundCloud.

[image: SoundCloud Mobile UI]
*(Image Credit:  [CreatedDigitalMusic.com](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2012/09/updated-soundcloud-app-boosts-mobile-recording-with-on-the-fly-editing-resume-ios-android/))*

I want to incorporate the scrubbing feature as well. Are there any open-source frameworks out there that replicate the features and look of the SoundCloud scrub bar? I have searched through SO and GitHub and have not been able to find anything similar.

Thanks.